# Calling a RPGIV function from SQL stored proc on DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2, rpg

Hi im trying to call a `RPGIV function` from a `stored proc`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "VEN60115"."TESTJCALL1" 
(IN ADUI CHAR(20),
OUT PRODOPIID1 CHAR(20))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
LANGUAGE RPGLE 
READS SQL DATA 
EXTERNAL NAME 'VEN60115/TESTJV'
PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL ;
```

When I test this in `SQL` by running:

```
Run VEN60115.TESTJCALL1(CHAR(20), CHAR(20))
```

The console returnes the following message:

```
VEN60115.TESTJCALL1 - Run started.
Data returned in result sets is limited to the first 0 rows.
Data returned in result set columns is limited to the first 100 bytes or characters.
VEN60115.TESTJCALL1 - Calling the stored procedure.
```

But the job hangs... Could anyone please help me.. or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your RPG code.  Where are you entering Run, and what are you actually sending in the parameters?

Comment: What I'm actualy trying to do is to call a RPGIV program(using sql stored proc) from java, I am able to call the program but then it hangs.. so what I did was first to try calling it in SQL dbb2 tool by just running the stored proc using the following statement. CALL VEN60115.TESTJCALL('aUsername','aPassword') then it hangs.. never finishes, I know that the rpgiv side works because we call the rpgiv program from other programs as well with no problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to call rpg functions using the IBM java api's instead of using Stored proc's from SQL.